# Casting from an abstract base class reference to derived class reference

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, reference, abstract-class

I have following C++ code

AbstractClass_01.h

```
class AbstractClass_01 {
public:
    virtual void method_01() = 0;
};
```

AbstractClass_02.h

```
class AbstractClass_02 {
public:
    virtual void method_02() = 0;
};
```

ClassA.h

```
#include "AbstractClass_02.h"

class ClassA : public AbstractClass_02{
    public:
        void method_02();
        void method_03();
};
```

ClassA.cpp

```
#include "ClassA.h"

void ClassA::method_02() {}

void ClassA::method_03() {}
```

ClassB.h

```
#include "AbstractClass_01.h"
#include "AbstractClass_02.h"

class ClassB : public AbstractClass_01 {
public:
    ClassB(AbstractClass_02& _obj);
    void method_01();
private:
    AbstractClass_02 &obj;
};
```

ClassB.cpp

```
#include "ClassB.h"
#include "ClassA.h"

ClassB::ClassB(AbstractClass_02& _obj) : obj(_obj) {}

void ClassB::method_01() {
    static_cast<ClassA&>(obj).method_03();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "ClassA.h"
#include "ClassB.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    ClassA a;
    ClassB b(a);
    
    b.method_01();
    
    return 0;
}
```

My question is whether the casting which I have done in the ClassB::method_01 is common C++ construct whether it is a sign of wrong design?

**EDIT**:

The reason why the `ClassB` constructor accepts references to the `AbstractClass_02` instead of the `ClassA` is that I need to pass references to various objects which all have common interface `AbstractClass_02`. The problem is that this interface doesn't contain the `method_03`. One possible solution could be to append that method into the interface `AbstractClass_02` but that method isn't cohesive with the `method_02`.

Comment: Like @Yksis mentions, this is an XY problem. Why do you need to take a `AbstractClass_02` in the constructor instead of just taking a `ClassA`?

Comment: If `ClassB` just needs to be able to pass `obj` as an `AbstractClass_02&` reference, there's no reason `obj` can't be a `ClassA&` that gets upcasted.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as [downcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting) and is typically a sign of bad design. Based on the limited knowledge we have, it seems obvious that you should take `ClassA` in constructor instead of `AbstractClass_01`

```
#include "AbstractClass_01.h"
#include "ClassA.h"

class ClassB : public AbstractClass_01 {
public:
    ClassB(ClassA & _obj);
    void method_01();
private:
    ClassA &obj;
};
```

But we don't know your real problem and why did you decide to go with casting or accepting interface in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please see the edit I have inserted to my question.